# how to link fortran library compiled with no-underscores with some compiled with underscores

Tags: fortran, mingw, linker-errors

I'm trying to compile and build the linear solver MUMPS (Fortran) on Windows with mingw, and link it with Matlab's blas and lapack (intel MKL). I'm compiling everything fine with mingw, however the final linking fails due to the Matlab blas/lapack being compiled without underscores (for Windows convention). Re-compiling everything with `-fno-underscoring` causes an avalanche of missing symbols with a lot of manual fixing.

Is there some way to conveniently specify which symbols should have *underscoring*, or what is the best way to approach this issue (Ideally I want to avoid recompiling and shipping a duplicate mkl with just redefined symbols)?

Answer (score 0):

Options like `no-underscoring` is a crude bulk way to control the symbols. You can get full control about the exported symbol with the `bind(C, name="symbol")` attribute in the declaration of your subroutines. However, that will require that that you always have explicit interface (best by placing them in a module) when using them inside Fortran and that they avoid certain features (e.g., only character arrays instead of full Fortran strings).

It sounds to me much more likely to be practical to set the symbols you need to call from Matlab to something specific using `bind(C)` and let the rest to the normal convention on your platform without any special flags.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, thinking about it a little, wouldn't it be better to effectively wrap the c-blas library with underscore functions (as they are the only ones changed.

Comment: @PatrickKwok That is up to you and completely depends on the overall structure of the project and relations to other libraries. But BLAS should not really be a source of problems. You should be able to compile BLAS with the no-underscoring options as well. Matlab is what requires some specific type of symbols and what you cannot easily change. There might be some interaction with the BLAS that Matlab uses internally. I do not know in what exact way Matlab integrates it.